# Azure MySQL In App: "MySQL In App export operation is in progress..."

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've tried to import database for Azure MySQL in App. Unfortunately, there were some connection issues. Now looks like importing stuck, MySQL in unavailable and I can't even delete the app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Finally after about a half an hour the service became available. For sure no actual import happened. So, for those googling the problem - just wait :(